# Copy large amout of files xargs

Tags: linux, xargs

I'm trying to copy large amount of file from one directory to another using xargs command. But this one does not seems to work right.

```
# echo * |xargs cp -r /directry/destination
```

what I am doing wrong?

Here is what it returns:

```
cp: target `file name' is not a directory
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```sh
find -maxdepth 1 -mindepth 1 -exec cp -r -t /directry/destination {} ';'
```

[Example](http://github.com/svnpenn/dotfiles/blob/9ef3af2/bootstrap.sh#L30)

Comment: +1 for working for working with all file names. You could also use `+` instead of `;` to make fewer invocations to cp.

Comment: No, it spreads out arguments across multiple invocations just like xargs.

Comment: @thatotherguy dumping a link to the manpage is not constructive. If I knew what you were talking about my answer would have already reflected that. I am not going to read 300 lines of the man just to figure out what you are on about.

Answer (score 0):

by default cp interprets the LAST argument as the target directory when there is more than one source directlry, but the way you have it, you have `cp -r target source1 source2 source3...`. So it is going to think you intend to copy things to the last source instead of the target.  If you are using gnu coreutils, you should have a `-t` or `--target-directory` switch so you can specify which directory you intend to use as the destination, so you could use `echo * | xargs cp -r --target-directory /directory/destination`